# Received-SPF: softfail when sending to google

Tags: gmail, spf

In the headers of an email it says:

> google.com: domain of transitioning ***@***.nl does not designate ****:***:**:****::* as permitted sender

We need this mail to be spam-free.

I know we have to add this IP(?) to the DNS-records as a txt but what kind of IP is it, and what would the txt record look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add proper SPF record in your DNS zone file for syntax of this record setup refer to:-[openspf](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax)

The spf record is like:-"`v=spf1 mx -all`"
to allow domain's MX's to send mail for the domain and prohibit all others.

Comment: Oke, the reference is pretty clear, thanks! I guess de IP I've got is an IPv6 than?

Comment: I dont know about your ip address whether it is ipv4 or ipv6.The syntax for both is given in my link i sent you.you can check whether your ip is ipv4 or ipv6 at:-http://ip-lookup.net/

Comment: Got it, it's IPv6.. I got it to work, thanks!

Comment: you are welcome!